# Hidden Pages, Posts & Plugins

Tags: pages

I am doing SEO on a woo-comerce site and when I got into wordpress there were no pages, posts or plugins listed in the bar to the left. Webmaster is using Mr. Builder and the only page I can find is About. Anyone have any ideas as to how to find the Pages, Posts & plugins. I think there is a plugin that hides all this. But the owner has no clue.

Help Please :-)

Jackie

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the required capabilities view those menu items.

Comment: Without seeing code, or knowing more about the installation (which plugins are there? which theme? Which user role are you using to login?) there isn't much we can do for you. As @nathan-johnson said, this is probably a capabilities issue, that's all it is possible to guess with current information.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce uses custom post types, so if the client hasn't actually created Pages/Posts all the content will be under labels like "Products." I would start by either determining whether there's an XML sitemap - if they have Yoast SEO installed, you'll see an "SEO" menu where you can check "XML Sitemaps" and generate one if there isn't one already, so you can see all the content WordPress is aware of - or if there is no XML sitemap, do a Google site: search and see what they have indexed. If everything is under sitename.com/products/ or sitename.com/shop/ or anything similar, it's likely they have only published Product content rather than Pages or Posts.

Once you have the list of URLs on the website you should be able to determine which URLs come from which post types. It would be extremely unusual for a site to "hide" Pages and Posts - it's more likely there just aren't any, other than the About page you found.